# sorting a table according to the result of a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of employees and I want to get the top three employees of the month.
I have a stored procedure that takes the employee ID and and returns a number indicating that employee quality of work.

I was hoping to find something like:

```
SELECT top (3)  name
FROM employee
order by sp_emplyeePerformance employee.ID -- of course this doesn't work
```

is such thing possible ? or should I create a temporary table with the employee name and performance and then query the temp table

Comment: You need to go the temp table route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for a [User Defined Function](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191320.aspx) instead of a Stored Proc. That UDF would  accept the employee's ID as a parameter and return a value (the employee's score), so you could sort by it.

Example :

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnEmployee_score (@employeeId INT)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    -- Your logic
    RETURN @score;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot execute a stored procedure from a `SELECT` query.

Your options are:

- Use a temporary table to store each employee Id, execute a stored procedure for each employee and then query the temporary table.
- Turn your stored procedure into a function.
- Change your store procedure to do the calculations on the whole `employee` in one go.